# C# Controller behavior changes based on variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I don't know enough about C#, .NET, or the MVC pattern to know exactly what is relevant to include here, but I'm pulling my hair out with a very simple change I'm working on.

I have a controller with a Search action (method?) that looks like:

```
public string Search(int id)
{
    return $"The id was {id}";
}
```

and when I hit the route I get the expected response, e.g.

```
$ curl https://localhost:7180/Players/Search/1
The id was 1
```

[image: expected behavior when visiting route]

but when I change the variable name from `id` to anything else, the behavior changes and the value goes to 0 for some reason.

```
public string Search(int thing)
{
    return $"The thing was {thing}";
}
```

```
$ curl https://localhost:7180/Players/Search/1
The thing was 0
```

[image: unexpected behavior when visiting route]

I thought maybe it had to do with the Model itself, because the model code at least has an `Id` attribute

```
    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

but renaming that variable to `name` (which seems analogous) also doesn't help.

So what concept am I missing here? Why can't I just rename that variable to whatever I want? Thanks in advance!

(I don't know how better to communicate all the different aspects of the code, so here is a [link to the line in question, inside the project](https://github.com/emgrasmeder/pingpong/blob/ask-stack-overflow/Controllers/PlayersController.cs#L50))

Comment: In your controller, try: `[HttpGet("{thing}")]
public string Search(int thing) { return $"The thing was {thing}"; }`

Comment: Ah, yes, in `Program.cs` I have the statement `app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default MVC registers (see either `Program` or `Startup`) next default route, so it can bind `id` parameter of method as positional part of path:

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You can change the parameter name for example using [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```
[Route("[controller]/search/{thing}")] 
public string Search(int thing)
{
    return $"The thing was {thing}";
}
```

Or using [HTTP verb templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#http-verb-templates):

```
[HttpGet("[controller]/search/{thing}")] 
public string Search(int thing)
{
    return $"The thing was {thing}";
}
```

Check the linked docs for other options/details.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to do with the way you've [defined your route](https://github.com/emgrasmeder/pingpong/blob/ask-stack-overflow/Program.cs#LL30-L33C56) in `Program.cs`:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You'll want to add a new definition like this:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "Players/Search/{thing?}");
```

or, you could use attribute-based route definitions to move the route pattern definition closer to the actual code. See the [MSFT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for details. Basically, add `app.MapControllers();` to `Program.cs`, then for your individual routes, do something like this:

```
[Route("Players/Search/{thing}")]
public string Search(int thing)
{
    return $"The thing was {thing}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate the method and define the parameter.

```
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<IEntity>> Get(string id)
    {
        var entity = await Repository.GetEntity(x => x.Id == id);
        if (entity == null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(entity);
    }
```

Here is another example of an API Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly GameDataContext context;

    public UserController(GameDataContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    // GET api/user
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>> Get()
    {
        

        return context.Users.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToArray();
    }

    // GET api/user/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetUser")]
    public ActionResult<User> Get(int id)
    {
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id && x.IsDeleted == false);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user;
        }

        return NotFound();
    }

    // GET api/user/username/5
    [HttpGet("username/{id}", Name = "GetUserByGameId")]
    public ActionResult<User> GetByUser(string gameId)
    {
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserGameId.Equals(gameId) && x.IsDeleted == false); 
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user;
        }

        return NotFound();
    }

    // POST api/user
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] User value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserGameId.Equals(value.UserGameId) && x.IsDeleted == false);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return BadRequest("User already exists!");
        }

        context.Users.Add(value);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { id = value.Id }, value);
    }

    // PUT api/user/steamId
    [HttpPut("{gameId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put(string gameId, [FromBody] User value)
    {
        if (value == null || !value.UserGameId.Equals(gameId))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserGameId.Equals(gameId) && x.IsDeleted == false); 
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        user.UserGameId = value.UserGameId;
        user.FirstName = value.FirstName;
        user.MiddleName = value.MiddleName;
        user.LastName = value.LastName;
        user.Email = value.Email;

        context.Users.Update(user);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();


        return new NoContentResult();
    }

    // DELETE api/user/steamId
    [HttpDelete("{gameId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string gameId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gameId))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserGameId.Equals(gameId) && x.IsDeleted == false);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        user.IsDeleted = true;
        context.Users.Update(user);

        var scores = context.Scores.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id);
        foreach (var score in scores)
        {
            score.IsDeleted = true;
            context.Scores.Update(score);
        }

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new NoContentResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! from what I can tell, using this decorator like that would assign `api` to `id` in the `GET api/values/5` example in your docstring. Using just your suggestion I get a 404 at my route (`/Players/Search/1`), but I see `"the thing was Players"` when I visit `/Players`

Comment: You are welcome! No it will assign "5" to "id"